# How to change `vcs_info:git` symbols when certain condition is meet

Tags: git, zsh, zshrc, zsh-zle

In my zsh prompt i have the following:

```
# LOCAL/VARIABLES/GRAPHIC
local char_next=":"

# SEGMENT/VCS_STATUS_LINE
local vc_branch_name="%B%F{yellow}%i %b%f%%b"
local vc_git_staged_status="%F{green}A%f"
local vc_unstaged_status="${char_next}%F{blue}M%f"
local vc_git_untracked_status="${char_next}%F{red}U%f"

autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git svn
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' check-for-changes true
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks use_git_untracked
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' stagedstr $vc_git_staged_status
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' unstagedstr $vc_unstaged_status
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats "${vc_branch_name} %c%u%m"
```

Which generates this prompt: `master A:M:U`, my problem with this is that whenever only one symbol is present example `master :M` which stands for modified files only it also prints the `:` symbol, how can i tell zsh to only display the `char_next` only when more than one symbol is present using the `zstyle` syntax?

I know this is possible because of this line:

```
PROMPT="%F{blue}%~%f`prepareGitStatusLine`
%(?.%F{yellow}.%F{red})${char_cmd}%f"
```

`%(?.%F{yellow}.%F{red})` turn my command prompt into yellow if the last command is succesfull otherwise turn it red. Again, how can i apply something like this to the above problem using `zstyle`?